# How can I find the ID of all meeting room calendars?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-online

Environment: Exchange Online and Wordpress

Issue: we are trying to connect and show Meeting Room Calendars to Worpress.

If I go to MS Graph, I can run a simple command to find a ID for my personal calendar. The command is:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars

It will return lots of values, the one we need is "id" that is very long, and not a GUID.

The ID value I need, looks like this:

"id": "AAMkADcxMzk2N2Y3LWFjMTktNGY1OS1hYLYwLTI3NzlkZDhMDAwZgBGAAAAAAAPB-v1RThsTKqjr5R_SEg0BwB83cbkVfyiT6pN-8Cf8VcaAAGGAAEGAB84cbkVfyiT6pN-8Cf8VcaAAAARYCdAAA="

I can then use this ID in Wordpress to show the calendar through a integration.

But I need to show the calendar for our Meeting rooms, I have been playing around in Graph with different values, but I cannot find the same "id" for the meeting room calendar.

Closest I get is using this command:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/c2c19414-c314-2d8f-be76f-9855727a209e/calendar

But I get error Not found 404 and a message: The specified object was not found in the store.

Any suggestions to how I can find the meeting room calendar ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, and all I neeeded was to first find a value on the Room  Mailbox Calendar that is named: "ExternalDirectoryObjectID". Then I took the value from this ID and used in the search string in MS Graph.

I have written a short guide to how I did it her:
https://www.blueclouds.no/post/how-to-find-the-right-id-for-a-room-mailbox-calendar

Answer (score 0):

The error `404` with the message **The specified object was not found in the store** is usually due to tenant policy which blocks access to some mailbox folders.

I'm using PowerShell [ExchangeOnlineManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps) module to [add mailbox folder permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/add-mailboxfolderpermission?view=exchange-ps)

```
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -Scope CurrentUser
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString '<password>' -AsPlainText -Force
$user = "admin@contoso.com"

$o365cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $secpasswd)

Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $o365cred

Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity {room_email}:\Calendar -User "{user_upn}" -AccessRights ReadItems

Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -Confirm:$false
```

- The `Identity` parameter specifies the target mailbox and folder. The syntax is **MailboxID:\ParentFolder[\SubFolder]**.
- The `User` parameter specifies who's granted permission to the mailbox folder.
- The [`AccessRights`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/add-mailboxfolderpermission?view=exchange-ps#-accessrights) parameter specifies the permissions that you want to add for the user on the mailbox folder.
  **ReadItems**: The user can read items within the specified folder.

Now, the user should be able to access only events and calendar of the meeting room.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{room_id}/calendar
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{room_id}/calendarView
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{room_id}/events
```